# Where is the create user (model) in the devise controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I want to add a serial number to a created user like I did here in a regular scaffold generation to a field named "code":

```
 def create
    @tester = Tester.new(tester_params)
    @tester.code =  @tester.created_at.to_s + ":" + rand(1235).to_s + ":" +      rand(5123).to_s + ":" + rand(1523).to_s + ":" + SecureRandom.base64
    respond_to do |format|
      if @tester.save
        format.html { redirect_to @tester, notice: 'Tester was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @tester }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @tester.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I generated a devise user and copied in the devise controller code to override the devise session handler. So I think I overided the code with devise's own code but I can't find where the user is created, I've been looking in the devise registration code:

```
def create
build_resource(sign_up_params)
resource.save
yield resource if block_given?
if resource.persisted?
  if resource.active_for_authentication?
    set_flash_message! :notice, :signed_up
    sign_up(resource_name, resource)
    respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  else
    set_flash_message! :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}"
    expire_data_after_sign_in!
    respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  end
else
  clean_up_passwords resource
  set_minimum_password_length
  respond_with resource
end
```

end

I have added_code_to_users, and now I want to do a 
current_user.code = secureRandom.base64 or something

Comment: It's `build_resource` + `resource.save`

Comment: Why not do this in the `before_create` callback in `User` model?

Comment: @Shobhit thank you that worked, you are a life saver if you were here I would smooch your balls personally. You're awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `resource` (the user) is created in `build_resource(sign_up_params)`.

However each action in Devise usually yields the resource.

```
yield resource if block_given?
```

This makes it pretty easy to extend simply by passing a block when calling `super`.

```
class TesterRegistrationContoller < Devise::RegistrationsController
  # ...
  def create
    super do |resource|
      # This runs before `.save` is called on the user.
      begin
        # do you really need all that other stuff?
        code = SecureRandom.uuid
      end while Tester.exists?(code: code)
      resource.code = code
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm going to try this also. I new to rails and never heard of most of this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

before_create :set_code
    def set_code
        self.code = SecureRandom.base64
    end
end
```